# Issue with building a .netcore3.1 proj within Azure pipeline. Failure only occurs when this proj references another proj (.net framework 4.7.2)

Tags: azure, build, azure-pipelines, publish

Basically, I have a .netcore 3.1 proj (an exe) that runs flawlessly locally, both with and without a reference to another class library proj (.net framework 4.7.2). However, when I try to get the .netcore3.1 proj to build in Azure it only works when there is no reference to the class library. If there is a reference to the .net framework 4.7.2 class library, the build fails.

Below is the error within the publish portion of the pipeline. This is what comes up when the related code and reference to the class library are being used.

```
##[debug]Exit code 1 received from tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[debug]STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=warning;].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. To mitigate such error, you can either: (1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, (2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, (3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated and now contain .Net 5.x SDK/Runtime along with the older .Net Core version which are currently lts. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 5.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions. You can learn more about the breaking changes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/ . To learn about more such changes and troubleshoot, refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting
##[debug]task result: Failed
##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\gwsCheckmarx\gwsCheckmarx.csproj
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\gwsCheckmarx\gwsCheckmarx.csproj
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : D:\a\1\s\gwsCheckmarx\gwsCheckmarx.csproj
Finishing: dotnet publish dotnetcore
```

I find it weird how locally it runs fine, but on Azure only works without the project reference. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid compatibility issues you should use for .NET Core 3.1 -> [.NET Standard 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md), because .NET Framework also implements .NET Standard, it is possible in some cases to include .NET Framework libraries in .NET Core projects but it is not a good practice.
If your app runs locally, the error can be because the dotnet sdk version that you are using locally is different that the one in the azure agent (from the error it is .NET 5). You can check by running this command in you local: `$ dotnet --version`

To [set an specific version of the dotnet sdk for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) you can execute this command in the root folder of your solution file `$ dotnet new globaljson`, it will generate a `global.json` file in which you can set the dotnet sdk version you have in your local.

Other option is set the dotnet version in the agent with `Use .NET Core` YAML task, and after that run the build.

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.401'
```

If you want to know the included software in the Azure pipeline VMs take a look at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software